# oData C# example code not compiling. Very basic

Tags: c#, odata

I am trying to get an oData Client to work, using the C# library `Simple.OData.Client`

As can be seen at http://www.odata.org/

```
var client = new ODataClient("http://services.odata.org/v4/TripPinServiceRW/");

var people = await client.For<People>().FindEntriesAsync();
```

These 2 lines are supposed to request a resource from the Server, but I can't compile this, as "People isn't being recognized. I have seen the specific notation `.For<People>()` in several oData examples, but no one ever explains or even mentions the "People" part.

What am I missing?

Comment: await client (there is a space in there....it's probably that)

Comment: await is an operator. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hh156528.aspx

Comment: `People` is a class model that needs to be defined before you can use it. The examples on the front page don't show the implementation of the `People` object... You need to add a service reference and I think the `People` object will be created when it discovers the service.

Comment: Do you have People class defined? What that line of code is doing is adding each entry on the People object but if you have not created the class definition it will not work. NOTE: when you put For<People>().function()  this actually means People is a type (class) that needs to be defined somewhere.

Comment: Thats what it looks like, but i see absolutely no frame work for that class. Like i said, i have seen it in a number of other examples, so it seams important. I assume there is a specific class that is supposed to fit here.

Comment: That is correct it wouldn't be on the odata client if you it's an example that considers the People class as the container for the data, where something like this would happen: DataContainer (dev defined) < oDataClient (framework) < DataSource (pre-defined). Check this out (I think will be helpful): https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client/wiki/Getting-started-with-Simple.OData.Client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Getting started with Simple.OData.Client](https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client/wiki/Getting-started-with-Simple.OData.Client), it mentions that:

> Example of typed fluent API syntax (**assuming there is a class Package defined** )

So, you should define the "People" CLR class first, then you can use it in the sample code.

I tried it out and it works fine. You can find my sample project [Here](https://github.com/xuzhg/WebApiSample/tree/master/SimpleODataClientTest)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thnx a tone.